# View below ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I've been struggling with this issue for days now and cannot find any similar issues online!

It seems to be simple and at first glance its actually really simple - to put a view just beneath a ScrollView.

I have two cases:

1. the rootlayout is RelativeLayout and I use **layout_below** in the View I want to place just below the ScrollView

What happends? Well no problem if there is just some content in the scrollview but if it's a larger list the ScrollView occupies all space and the View (Button) below is no longer there

[image]

[image]

2. Instead of using layout_below I use **align_parent_bottom="true"** and then It works (the button is always there) but there's an ugly large white space in between the button and the ScrollView

[image]

notice: The items in the ScrollView are added dynamically and put in a LinearLayout that is part of the ScrollView. Also notice that the button (draghandle) is just an Ad Hoc button at the moment.

**xml-layout source**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appinfo_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
    
        >
    
    
        <!-- TOP LAYOUT -->
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout_appinfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/launcher_iv"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mbi" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appname_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/launcher_iv"
                android:text="APPNAMN"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appinfo_settings_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/outline_more_vert_black_36" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    
    
        <!-- ALL  DATA I SCROLLVIEW -->
    
    
    
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/appinfo_scrollv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
            android:layout_below="@id/top_layout_appinfo"
    
            >
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appinfo_gridLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:columnCount="2"
                    app:rowCount="12">
    
                    <!-- PACKAGE -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/packagename_tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="PACKAGENAME"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/packagename_tv_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="cell2"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    
                    <!-- VERSION -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/version_tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="VERSION"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/version_tv_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0.000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    
    
                    <!-- MIN SDK -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/min_sdk_tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MIN SDK"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/min_sdk_tv_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0.000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    
    
                    <!-- MAX SDK -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/target_sdk_tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MAX SDK"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/target_sdk_tv_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0.000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    
                    <!-- SIZE SDK -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/size_tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SIZE"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/size_tv_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0.000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    
    
                    <!-- ENABLED SDK -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/enable_tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ENABLED"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/enable_tv_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    
    
                </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
    
    
                <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/permissions_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PERMISSIONS"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                <!-- TILL DENNA LAYOUT SKAPAS I KÄLLKODEN TEXVIEWS DYNAMISKT SOM LÄGGS PÅ DENNA LAYOUT-->
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/permissions_ll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
        </ScrollView>
    
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:src="@drawable/draghandle">
    
        </ImageButton>
    
    
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

So the question is how do I solve this? A layout that always keeps the Button just below the ScrollView not matter the height of the Fragment?

Comment: use `layout_below` param properly instead of `alignParentBottom`, `ImageButton` should also have `layout_below` `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 (ConstraintLayout - with scrollView maxHeight)**

In case you want to have always the button visible and below Scrollview you can achieve this behaviour using a root parent of ConstraintLayout. You have to constraint the button to be always below of ScrollView and set in ScrollView the attribute **app:layout_constraintHeight_max** to set its max possible height when the text is too long. You can change this value based on your needs even programmatically.
The xml layout is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appinfo_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <!-- TOP LAYOUT -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout_appinfo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/launcher_iv"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mbi" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appname_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/launcher_iv"
            android:text="APPNAMN"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appinfo_settings_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/outline_more_vert_black_36" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- ALL  DATA I SCROLLVIEW -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/appinfo_scrollv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="500dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_layout_appinfo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/appinfo_gridLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="12">

                <!-- PACKAGE -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/packagename_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PACKAGENAME"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/packagename_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="cell2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- VERSION -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/version_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="VERSION"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/version_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                <!-- MIN SDK -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/min_sdk_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MIN SDK"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/min_sdk_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                <!-- MAX SDK -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/target_sdk_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MAX SDK"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/target_sdk_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- SIZE SDK -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/size_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SIZE"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/size_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- ENABLED SDK -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/enable_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ENABLED"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/enable_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


            </GridLayout>

            <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/permissions_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PERMISSIONS"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- TILL DENNA LAYOUT SKAPAS I KÄLLKODEN TEXVIEWS DYNAMISKT SOM LÄGGS PÅ DENNA LAYOUT-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/permissions_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lorem_small"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/draghandle"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appinfo_scrollv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the results with above layout will be like below.
The 1st image is a sample with small text, 2nd image is a sample with a normal text and the 3rd image is a sample with a very long text (where ScrollView has its max Height based on app:layout_constraintHeight_max attribute and the vertical scrolling is enabled).

[image: small_text]
[image: medium_text]
[image: long_text]

**Option 2 (LinearLayout - with layout_weight)**

In case you want to fill the entire screen and you don't want to set a fixed maxHeight to your ScrollView you can simply do that using a parent (root) of Linear Layout. You have to set **android:layout_weight="0**" to your top Relative Layout and your ImageButton and set   **android:layout_weight="1"** to your ScrollView.

The new xml layout with a Linear Layout (root) will be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appinfo_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <!-- TOP LAYOUT -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout_appinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/launcher_iv"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mbi" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appname_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/launcher_iv"
            android:text="APPNAMN"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appinfo_settings_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/outline_more_vert_black_36" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- ALL  DATA I SCROLLVIEW -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/appinfo_scrollv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/appinfo_gridLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="12">

                <!-- PACKAGE -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/packagename_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PACKAGENAME"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/packagename_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="cell2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- VERSION -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/version_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="VERSION"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/version_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                <!-- MIN SDK -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/min_sdk_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MIN SDK"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/min_sdk_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                <!-- MAX SDK -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/target_sdk_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MAX SDK"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/target_sdk_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- SIZE SDK -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/size_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SIZE"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/size_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                <!-- ENABLED SDK -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/enable_tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ENABLED"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/enable_tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </GridLayout>


            <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/permissions_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PERMISSIONS"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- TILL DENNA LAYOUT SKAPAS I KÄLLKODEN TEXVIEWS DYNAMISKT SOM LÄGGS PÅ DENNA LAYOUT-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/permissions_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lorem_small"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/draghandle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the results with a small/medium/large text will be like below:

[image: small2]
[image: medium2]
[image: large2]

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution where the button is fixed, i.e always visible

Comment: Check my updated answer it should solve your issue, the button now is always visible and below scrollview

Comment: thanks, will look into this and may accept the answer if successful